# Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl'

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I have xampp installed on my Windows 10 machine. Running php from command prompt gives error as below.

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: D:\xamp\php\ext\openssl 
(The specified module could not be found.), D:\xamp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll 
(The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

In php.ini for extension_dir I tried giving absolute path as well as relative path to extension directory.
File is available in location D:\xamp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll. It still gives the error.

Comment: All other dynamic libraries are getting loaded

Answer (score 0):

php will also give that exact error if `libcrypto-1_1.dll` or `libssl-1_1.dll` are missing, even if `php_openssl.dll` is present and `php.ini` configured correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check if the loaded php.ini is the correct one ?
`php --ini`
also you can check php -m to check the loaded extension in cmd using
`php -m | findstr "xml"`

also you can try to manually download the openssl extension:
http://www.dlldownloader.com/php_openssl-dll/

Comment: php --ini shows correct loaded configuration. php -m does not list openssl in the list of modules. I tried installing new php-openssl.dll from the link provided that also did not work.

Comment: can you provide any capture?